# Variable is used before it's been assigned a value and now data doesn't filter

Tags: vb.net, datatable

So I have code that filters a datatable by multiple criteria. Every other criteria works fine but those are based on textboxes. so the code is just

```
Dim SubjFilter As String = "Subjects = '" & TxtSubj.Text & " '"
```

and then is identical to the bottom of the code below. That prints the row in the listbox just fine, but when i try to do it with radio buttons it can't seem to find the criteria. In the CSV every row in the 4th column has a piece of info that is either 75+ or 85+ or something, so I know that's not the issue. No error is coming up it's just a case of it not being able to find anything in that category or maybe something wrong with how i'm printing it in the listbox. Any sort of insight would be appreciated as i'm lost right now.

```
Dim ATARFilter As String
    If RBtn70.Checked = True Or
    Rbtn75.Checked = True Or
    RBtn80.Checked = True Or
    Rbtn85.Checked = True Or
    Rbtn90.Checked = True Or
    Rbtn95.Checked = True Then 'if any of the radiobuttons are checked then the same printing process as before is done

        If RBtn70.Checked = True Then
            ATARFilter = "ATAR = '70+'"
        ElseIf Rbtn75.Checked = True Then
            ATARFilter = "ATAR = '75+'"
        ElseIf RBtn80.Checked = True Then
            ATARFilter = "ATAR = '80+'"
        ElseIf Rbtn85.Checked = True Then
            ATARFilter = "ATAR = '85+'"
        ElseIf Rbtn90.Checked = True Then
            ATARFilter = "ATAR = '90+'"
        ElseIf Rbtn95.Checked = True Then
            ATARFilter = "ATAR = '95+'" 'all of these just set the string value of the filter to be equal to whatever is on the RadioButton
            Dim FilteredRowsATAR As DataRow() = TutorTable.Select(ATARFilter)
            For Each row As DataRow In FilteredRowsATAR
                ListBox1.Items.Add(String.Format("{0},  {1},  {2},  {3},  {4},  {5}", row("Name"), row("Age"), row("Subjects"), row("ATAR"), row("Location"), row("PhNumber")))
            Next
        End If
    End If
```

Comment: Rip the extra space out of filter, `TxtSubj.Text & " '"` should be `TxtSubj.Text & "'"`... IMHO also change your `Or` to `OrElse`.

Comment: I'm confused by what you mean as rip the extra space out, what extra space?

Comment: It looks like your Select will only be applied if Rbtn95 is true.

Answer (score 0):

This bit of code requires Imports System.Linq . Checking Is Nothing says nothing is checked

```
Private Sub OPCode()
            Dim ATARFilter As String = ""
            Dim rButton As RadioButton = GroupBox1.Controls.OfType(Of RadioButton).FirstOrDefault(Function(r) r.Checked = True)
            If rButton Is Nothing Then
                MessageBox.Show("Please make a selection.")
                Exit Sub
            Else
                ATARFilter = rButton.Text 'or if the exact text cannot not appear
                ' in the text of the radio button then store it in the .Tag property
                'at design time and change code to = CStr(rButton.Tag)
            End If
            Dim FilteredRowsATAR As DataRow() = TutorTable.Select(ATARFilter)
            For Each row As DataRow In FilteredRowsATAR
                ListBox1.Items.Add(String.Format("{0},  {1},  {2},  {3},  {4},  {5}", row("Name"), row("Age"), row("Subjects"), row("ATAR"), row("Location"), row("PhNumber")))
            Next
        End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Only the last condition in your ElseIf contains the code for applying the filter, you need to move it outside of the block

```
Dim ATARFilter As String
    If RBtn70.Checked = True Or
    Rbtn75.Checked = True Or
    RBtn80.Checked = True Or
    Rbtn85.Checked = True Or
    Rbtn90.Checked = True Or
    Rbtn95.Checked = True Then 'if any of the radiobuttons are checked then the same printing process as before is done

        If RBtn70.Checked = True Then
            ATARFilter = "ATAR = '70+'"
        ElseIf Rbtn75.Checked = True Then
            ATARFilter = "ATAR = '75+'"
        ElseIf RBtn80.Checked = True Then
            ATARFilter = "ATAR = '80+'"
        ElseIf Rbtn85.Checked = True Then
            ATARFilter = "ATAR = '85+'"
        ElseIf Rbtn90.Checked = True Then
            ATARFilter = "ATAR = '90+'"
        ElseIf Rbtn95.Checked = True Then
            ATARFilter = "ATAR = '95+'" 'all of these just set the string value of the filter to be equal to whatever is on the RadioButton
        End If

        Dim FilteredRowsATAR As DataRow() = TutorTable.Select(ATARFilter)
        For Each row As DataRow In FilteredRowsATAR
            ListBox1.Items.Add(String.Format("{0},  {1},  {2},  {3},  {4},  {5}", row("Name"), row("Age"), row("Subjects"), row("ATAR"), row("Location"), row("PhNumber")))
        Next
    End If
```